# Redirect users not logged in to the standard login page (and back) from some posts and pages

Tags: php, redirect, login, codex

I'm looking for a hand-coded solution to do the following:

- in some pages (so, not every page) I want to redirect the users NOT logged in to the standard login page: when they login, they are automatically redirected to the page where they were;
- same for some posts;

I tested many free plugins but I was really not satisfied: some moves the login form in the protected page, some other lets you put a link to the login page.

I'm quite surprised "vanilla WP" doesn't offer a login option like the one I'm looking for: you can set a private post, but then it is really private (not to say invisible), then there's a password solution, but I don't see many website using this idea, it's quite uncommon, imho.

Anyway, I would like to know where I can find information about how to code this behaviour myself: there are lots of resources but it looks like anybody has a "snippet" but nothing is "definitive".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is_user_logged_in()` and `is_page (array(1,2,3-page id's))` functions to check. After that you can write the redirection.

Comment: Ok, but what I see online is people cutting and pasting code literally everywhere: I edited single.php, for example, and it worked, but I can't find any robust documentation about what's the best way to code a thing like this

Comment: I think below linked question also has your same issue, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56875/redirect-to-requested-page-after-custom-login?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Well i have not tested it but you can achieve your point in this way...

```
  if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page(1,2,your-page-ids)){

   // wp_redirect(LOGIN_PAGE_URL.'?redirect_to='.get_the_permalink(););

    }
```

redirect user to login page with a query variable containing link of post or page.

put this code in your child theme's function.php

Hope it will help you...

Answer (score -1):

Put this CODE in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function admin_default_page() {
    return '/new-url';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

Comment: Problem is new-url is dynamic (it can be some posts and some pages)

Comment: please, if you are going to post an answer, try to format the code correctly. In addition answers should have some explanation about how they actually solve the issue, not just a dump of code